# Remover atributo onclick por JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Boa tarde, gostaria de saber como faço para remover o onClick do input utilizando a própria função que está no onClick.

Por exemplo, no meu caso eu tenho os seguintes input:

```
<input type="submit" class="adduser" onClick="addUser(valor);" value="Adicionar">
<input type="submit" class="adduser" onClick="addUser(valor2);" value="Adicionar">
<input type="submit" class="adduser" onClick="addUser(valor3);" value="Adicionar">
```

Eu gostaria de que quando a pessoa clicar em um desses inputs a função do onClick ativaria e no fim da função fazer com que esse input clicado perdesse a função onClick, alterasse a class para adduser2 e ganhasse o value = Sucesso.

ficando da seguinte maneira caso clicado no primeiro input:

```
<input type="submit" class="adduser2" value="Sucesso">
```

Obrigado!

Comment: Você poderia melhorar sua pergunta? E se possível coloca o código de exemplo, isso ajuda a entender! ;)

Comment: @kayoBruno  fiz alteração na pergunta. Veja se ficou melhor de entender.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aqui tem um exemplo de como remover o atributo `onclick` com jQuery dentro da prória função referenciada inline (`onclick="..."`):

```js
function addUser(valor, ele) {
   console.log('botão com o valor: ' +valor);
   // fazer tudo o que tem para fazer
   $(ele).val('Sucesso');
   $(ele).prop('onclick',null).off('click');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" class="adduser" onClick="addUser(11, this);" value="Adicionar">
<input type="submit" class="adduser" onClick="addUser(22, this);" value="Adicionar">
<input type="submit" class="adduser" onClick="addUser(33, this);" value="Adicionar">
```

Comment: alterei a minha pergunta veja se ficou melhor de entender. Obrigado!

Comment: Feito @rhundler

Answer (score 5):

rhundler, primeiro aconselho que leia o seguinte artigo.:

[`Why Inline CSS And JavaScript Code Is Such A Bad Thing`](https://robertnyman.com/2008/11/20/why-inline-css-and-javascript-code-is-such-a-bad-thing/)

agora vamos à um exemplo sem jQuery para complementar à resposta do Miguel.

```js
var onDoSomethingClick = function (event) {
  alert("button#" + event.target.id + " clicado");
  event.target.removeEventListener("click", onDoSomethingClick);
}

var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("doSomething");
[].forEach.call(buttons, function (button, indice) {
  button.addEventListener("click", onDoSomethingClick);
});
```

```html
<button id="btn1" class="doSomething">Botão 1</button>
<button id="btn2" class="doSomething">Botão 2</button>
<button id="btn3" class="doSomething">Botão 3</button>
<button id="btn4" class="doSomething">Botão 4</button>
<button id="btn5" class="doSomething">Botão 5</button>
```