# Onclick chamar duas funções ao mesmo tempo Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

Bom dia, e possivel quando clicar em um botao executar pelo onclick duas funcoes ao mesmo tempo, ex: dois alert diferentes?

Comment: Quando dizes _"duas funcoes ao mesmo tempo"_  queres dizer "só com uma ação fazer correr as duas"?

Comment: Não recomendo de usar 2 funções no mesmo tempo, por exemplo se chamar função for falhar e parar todas chamas funções e não vai seguir chamada a segunda função. Assim recomendo de usar apenas 1 função e enquanto dar sucesso para chamar outro função. É simples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se percebi bem a duvida acho que é isto:

```js
function funcao_a() {
  alert('funcao A');
}
function funcao_b() {
  alert('funcao B');
}
```

```html
<button id="btn" onclick="funcao_a();funcao_b();">Clica</button>
```

A meu entender (que não é muito extenso), pode colocar javascript dentro do `onclick=".."` ou [outro evento qualquer](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp), e assim chama as duas ou mais funções que queira

Caso tenha muitas funções, não vai querer que essas fiquem todas dentro do `onclick="..."`, pode fazer:

```js
var funcs_bt1 = {
  func1: function() {
    alert('bt1 func1'); 
  },
  func2: function() {
    alert('bt1 func2'); 
  },
  func3: function() {
    alert('bt1 func3'); 
  }
};
var funcs_bt2 = {
  func1: function() {
    alert('bt2 func1'); 
  },
  func2: function() {
    alert('bt2 func2'); 
  },
  func3: function() {
    alert('bt2 func3'); 
  }
};
function call_funcs(ele) {
  var id = ele.id;
  if(id == 'btn1') {
    var funcs = funcs_bt1;
  }
  else {
    var funcs = funcs_bt2;
  }
  for(i in funcs) {
    funcs[i]();
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="btn1" onclick="call_funcs(this);">btn1</button>
<button id="btn2" onclick="call_funcs(this);">btn2</button>
```

Comment: E se forem 6 funções? Vais sugerir `<button id="btn" onclick="funcao_a();funcao_b();funcao_c();funcao_d();funcao_e();funcao_f();">Clica</button>`? :)

Comment: Nesse caso, talvez pusesse a chamar uma e essa uma chamava as outras @Sergio. O AP falou em duas

Comment: Seria interessante juntar essa sugestão.

Comment: @Sergio, sem falar que se por algum motivo durante o ciclo de vida da pagina ele quiser que a `funcaoB` não seja mais chamada, ele não vai conseguir bloquear apenas ela.

Comment: @TobyMosque exato. Limita muito.

Comment: @TobyMosque, mas ele consegueria removar o `onclick="..."` dentro de qualquer seja a função chamada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/143213/remover-atributo-onclick-por-javascript/143217#143217

Comment: Miguel, para tal você terá de desenvolver o seu próprio `EventListener` caseiro, que por sua vez será menos robusto, menos eficaz e possivelmente mais lento, isto se quiser remover apenas uma função... caso remova o `onclick` estará removendo todo o fluxo.

Comment: Percebi @TobyMosque . Se dependesse de mim tirava a resposta, mas não consigo porque já foi aceite

Answer (score 6):

A solução do TobyMosque serve perfeitamente, mas para lhe dar outra alternativa, vou lhe mostrar outra maneira de resolver o problema. Esse exemplo serve para caso você deseje adicionar os eventos e não pretende mais trabalhar com eles (remover um em específico, adicionar novos, "substituir" um evento), você pode criar uma função que una todas as demais funções e adicionar somente ela ao escutador. Eu recomendaria uma função auxiliar para esse caso, como uma função de composição com o operador bitwise and. Ficaria algo assim:

```
var clickMe = document.getElementById("clickMe");
var reduce = Function.call.bind(Array.prototype.reduce);

var bitAnd = function(f, g) {
  return function() {
    return g.apply(this, arguments) & f.apply(this, arguments);
  }
}

bitAnd.all = function() {
  return reduce(arguments, bitAnd);
}

function funcaoA(a) {
  alert('funcao A' + a);
}

function funcaoB(a) {
  alert('funcao B' + a);
}

clickMe.addEventListener('click', bitAnd.all(funcaoA, funcaoB));
```

Note que a ordem de chamada das funções é do último argumento para o primeiro argumento (direita para esquerda), ou seja, `funcaoB` será chamada primeira e depois `funcaoA`.

Answer (score 5):

de forma `inline` ou setando o `onclick` não, porém é possível adicionar um `EventListener` ao `DOM`.

```js
var clickMe = document.getElementById("clickMe");

var funcaoA = function functionA(event) {
  console.log(funcaoA.name);
}

var eventHandler = {
  name: "eventHandler", 
  handleEvent: function (event) {
    console.log(eventHandler.name);
  }  
}

clickMe.addEventListener("click", funcaoA);
clickMe.addEventListener("click", function functionB(event) {
  console.log(functionB.name);
});
clickMe.addEventListener("click", eventHandler);
```

```html
<input id="clickMe" type="button" value="Click Me" />
```

Answer (score 5):

Vitor, você pode chamar quantas funções desejar as separando por `;` assim:

```
<input type="button" onClick="javarscipt:alert('Funcao 1');alert('Funcao2')">
```

Mas o melhor seria chamar uma função que chama outras:

```
<input type="button" onClick="javarscipt:funcoes()">


<script>
function funcoes() {
    funcao1();
    funcao2('Stack');
    funcao2('Overflow');
}

funcao1() {
    alert('Funcao 1');
}

funcao2(txt) {
    alert(txt);
}

</script>
```

Como o alert é uma função que bloqueia o navegador, até que seja clicado em OK, não é possível que sejam exibidos 2 ao mesmo tempo. Você pode escolher exibir alguma mensagem na tela. Exemplo:
http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_alerts.asp