# Criar uma função javascript para todos os botões da aplicação

Tags: javascript, html5, javascript-eventos, button

Galera, gostaria de criar uma função javascript para todos os botões da aplicação, ou seja, todo botão quando for clicado ele chamará essa função.

Obs: Sem a necessidade de colocar em cada botão o onclick.

Obrigado!!

Comment: @EliseuB. Uma das respostas ([esta aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/143220/8063)) não usa jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
var buttonsCount = buttons.length;
for (var i = 0; i < buttonsCount; i += 1) {
    buttons[i].onclick = function(e) {
        alert(this.id);
        // O que quer que ele faça
    };
}
```

```css
button {
padding: 10px;
font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<button id='1'>Clique</button>
<button id='2'>Clique</button>
<button id='3'>Clique</button>
<button id='4'>Clique</button>
```

Comment: Resolveu meu problema, obrigado!!!